# Find certain instances in string, find certain instances in found string, replace

Tags: html, regex, replace, find

I have a string.

```
string2 = '...his awesome effort in last <span style="font-family: 'arial black', 'avant     garde';">night's</span> matchup.'
```

I need to replace the single quotes around arial black and avant-garde with double quotes. I have a pretty big string that is similar to my example string2. There are more span tags that have single quotes around their font names. I need to replace them all with doubles. Even if I use regular expressions, how can I use it?

Comment: Do you want to do it in server side code(php) or client side(html/js) code?

Comment: I need to do it in javascript, client side @souvickcse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below string to match any instance of 'arial black' or 'avant garde'

```
'(avant garde|arial black)'
```

And you can replace the single quotes with double quotes using this

```
"\1"
```

Where the  \1  refers to the first capturing group (this stuff between the parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

If you have all same font name, you can try this code

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "font-family: 'arial black', 'avant     garde'"; 
    var res = replaceAll("'",'"',str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
var find = 'abc';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
str = str.replace(re, '');
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
</script>
```

But for only removing the font family ' you have to find all the string containing only the font family part as in my code `str`